# Is the task of Web API in browser same as the task of thread pool in Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, threadpool, event-loop

For Javascript in Browser and node.js, I am trying to understand the difference between the thread pool and Web API.
Both the thread pool, and Web API, enable Javascript to handle asynchronous behavior, so how they are different?  Web API after completion of the task sends the task to the Queues from where the task is sent back to the call stack. How do Thread Pool and NodeJS work to imitate asynchronous behavior?

Comment: Please clarify **exactly** what you mean by "Web API" - what _which_ thread-pool are you referring to? Please link to any (authoritative) documentation you've seen.

Comment: "Web API after completion of the task sends the task to the Queues from where the task is sent back to the call stack" whatever you mean by "Web API" this is not how things work no. The task is first pushed in a queue, then it eventually gets picked and executed and if that task involves executing a JS script, that script will be put on the call stack. Once that script is executed the task will continue to do what it was told to do (e.g after every JS call, it does visit the microtask queue), and then only the task will be completed. JS execution (may be) part of what a task does.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely unrelated.

---

The main event loop is where most JavaScript code you write runs.

Expensive operations (such as file access or code you explicitly run in a worker) are often done outside of the main event loop. This frees up the main event loop to do *other work*.

We say something is asynchronous when it is performed outside the main event loop because it isn't done in sequence with the rest of the work the main event loop is doing.

The thread pool is just how Node.js' particular implementation manages those asynchronous tasks.

---

The Web APIs are a set of classes/functions/etc provided to JavaScript programs that run in browsers which have functionality that is often desired in JS programs that are embedded in webpages but which are not part of the JavaScript language.

e.g. [the Object constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-constructor) is a core part of JavaScript, while [the HTML DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API) is a Web API.

Some of those features (such as XMLHttpRequest) do work outside the main event loop, but that isn't an intrinsic feature of Web APIs (e.g. the DOM API doesn't).

Node.js puts APIs not defined by the ECMAScript specification in built-in modules (such as the `fs` module).